# how do i check if all rows have similiar data in one column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

so I am working on restaurant and I have tables(I am referring to actual table not sql table) and clients in each table, I am having trouble making a query that returns the table_ID of the tables that contains only customers from the one family
for the following table named a :

```
costumer_name|| table_ID 
-----        ||----
Levi         ||   1
Levi         ||   1
Levi         ||   1
Levi         ||   1
Cohen        ||   2
Cohen        ||   2
shalev       ||   3
shalev       ||   3
shalev       ||   3
shalev       ||   3
jacob        ||   3
```

the output will be only table 1 and 2 because in table 3, there are shalev and jacob.
i have managed to make it work only with a specific table using a condition (which table_ID)
example for tablenumber 1:

```
select family_name,table_ID from clients 
group by table_id
having table_id = '1' and count(distinct family_name) =1
```

I can do it manually for each table_ID but is it possible to do it in one query?
I am having trouble doing it

Comment: Can you post your expected result as well?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the whether it is customer_name/family_name i used `customer_name`.

```
select count(distinct customer_name) as total, table_ID
from clients
group by table_ID
having total = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

you can just check the records where count of family_name is 1

```
select Min(family_name) family_name, table_ID from clients 
group by table_id
having count(family_name) = 1
```